# Why is DelegeateCommand.Execute() not actually executing?

Tags: mvvm, prism

I have the following command that should autoclick a button:

public DelegateCommand AutoClickFadeinButtonCommand { get; set; }

in constructor:

```
AutoClickFadeinButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => AutoClickFadeinButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged());
```

and then somewhere, I just call:

```
AutoClickFadeinButtonCommand.Execute();
```

I checked with the debugger, and it executes this line, but nothing happens. What may be the problem? I assume some threading....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a command that when executed only calls AutoClickFadeinButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged.  So nothing actually happens. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Hi Brian, this command is bound to a button, and i expect button to auto-click when this command is executed and then to cause some other ui elements to fade in

Comment: You haven't provided any logic to do that in the Execute delegate.

Comment: Ok, i can do that, but is it going to violate mvvm? The code i was referring to is in ViewModel class, so if I use button control in this class, that is probably going to violate mvvm...

Comment: I didn't say to use a button control. I said you need to have logic in your Execute delegate for your command.  Right now you have no logic that would be performed when the command is invoked.

Comment: Can you please give me some hint on how to write the logic for this command that would auto-click the button in VM without directly referring the button control?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused.  Commands are bound to buttons. The common use case is to click a button to invoke a command which in turns executes logic within the ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, I know, maybe I am on completely wrong track...I am trying to do kind of the opposite thing....I want some kind of event in my VM that would cause a button in xaml to auto-click

Comment: Then that's the question you should ask.  I would suggest marking this answer as correct, and then opening another question.

Comment: Yes, will do. Thank you.